# OpenGL GL_POINTS result differs from input

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I want to draw something with GL_POINTS but after ~totalpoint/3 result starts differ from input by 1 pixel

I tried different glOrtho and glViewport arguments but nothing changed

my test program:

```
int w = atoi(argv[1]);
int h = atoi(argv[2]);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, 1.0, -1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glLoadIdentity();

unsigned int wf,hf;
unsigned char rgb[3];

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPointSize(1);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(hf=0;hf<h;hf++){
        for(wf=0;wf<w;wf++){
            memset(rgb,0,3);
            rgb[wf%3]=0xff;
            glColor3ub(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);
            glVertex2f(wf,hf);
        }
    }
    glEnd();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Results:

Not Colored

[image: not colored]

Colored

[image: colored]

Comment: Windows has a famous RECT issue. right and bottom are actually outside the rectangle by 1 pixel.  You need to play with the RECT returned by GetClientRect to get the right width and height for OpenGL, which doesn't follow the same rules.

Comment: Many thanks Minchael Roy its worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Roy's way its solved my problem i just changed this line

```
GLFWwindow* wmain = glfwCreateWindow(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), "test", 0, 0);
```

to

```
GLFWwindow* wmain = glfwCreateWindow(atoi(argv[1]) + 1, atoi(argv[2]) + 1, "test", 0, 0);
```

Comment: Don't forget that you have to do the same for the height.